# FileNotFoundException even when file placed in the same folder as the class files

Tags: java

I read a file `big.txt` to poulate my HashMap. I have placed the file along side the `class` files in the `bin` folder.

However, whenever I want to use it, it gives an error saying `java.io.FileNotFoundException ( No such file or directory )`.

How is this happening ?

```
public ClassName() throws IOException{
        URL url = ClassName.class.getResource("big.txt");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
        BufferedReader inp= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        // some code
        }
        inp.close();        
    }
```

Why is this happening ? Plaese help me out here !

Comment: You already have the URL, just call `openStream()` which will return an `InputStream`. Use that with an `InputStreamReader`

Comment: Put it in your working directory, i.e. where you start the program from.

Comment: Print out the URL's path to see what you're really doing. I wouldn't mix URL's with file but rather would stick with one or the other.

Comment: just print out url.getPath() and see where it points to.

Comment: Well, the problem is its runnning on windows and not on Mac. so will passing an absolute path be a good idea ??

Comment: just print out url.getPath() and see where it points to.

Comment: @CSSS Don't use Files with classpath resources. Just do what I posted or call `ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: @IsmetAlkan : It prints the same thing as the address of the file not found printed below !!

Comment: any chance the file name has a trailing space?

Comment: @IsmetAlkan: Doesn't seem so !!

Comment: @CSSS Getting the path and creating a `File` instance from it won't work if you are running this from a jar. It might work here because Eclipse loads classes from bin folder.

Comment: have you tried the answers? what happened when you did? another guess is: the file doesn't give permission to read?

Comment: @IsmetAlkan: Yeah !! got it.. Sotirios's answer is working great !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access any resource you have on the classpath with

```
public ClassName() throws IOException{
        // the path to your file is relative to the package of ClassName
        InputStream input = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("big.txt"); 

        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

        // some code

        inp.close();        
}
```

or

```
URL url = ClassName.class.getResource("big.txt");
// check for null first
InputStream input = url.openStream();
BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, I believe that it actually looks in the project folder but not within the bin folder for the files, depending on settings. You should try moving big.txt there, but also the other answers are good for if you want to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ClassName() throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("big.txt"));
        //your stuff       
}
```

Comment: You should explain your code a bit, e.g. what is a Scanner etc.